# Static toolbar icons ontop

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I am working on a Android-L-test-app with some features of the material-design-guide. Im trying to implement a toolbar, where the icons a static on top.

It was done in the google IO 2014 app and I would like to replicate it. I have been looking through the code (https://github.com/google/iosched) but I can't figure out how they done it.

here are a screenshot to visualize my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub7KQ.jpg

left side: a screenshot of my actual situation (the menu icons are hard in the header and scroll with these)
right side: this is what i want to have ("static" icons on top of the screen"):

Any ideas?

layout.xml:

```
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar" />

        <!-- Session title -->
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_2_session_detail"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/keyline_1"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_session_title"
            android:id="@+id/session_title"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            android:textStyle="@integer/font_textStyle_medium"
            android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/body_text_1_inverse" />
        <!--android:textAlignment="viewStart" -->


        <!-- Session subtitle -->
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_2_session_detail"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/keyline_1"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_session_subtitle"
            android:id="@+id/session_subtitle"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/body_text_2_inverse" />
            <!--android:textAlignment="viewStart" -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

layout toolbar_actionbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    iosched:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    iosched:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:background="@null"
    iosched:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText"
    iosched:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
/>
```

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_map_room"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_map"
    android:title="@string/description_map"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    iosched:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    android:title="@string/description_share"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    iosched:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_social_stream"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_social_stream"
    android:title="@string/description_social_stream"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:visible="true"
    iosched:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the main content into a scrollview and the toolbar out of it. Then you should use a fading effect when you scroll it.

1. RelativeLayout to all screen
2. Toolbar inside RelativeLayout align parent top, transparent.
3. ScrollView inside RelativeLayout to all screen.
4. Toolbar from transparent to your theme color when you scrolldown X distance your scrollView and viceversa.

You can get colorPrimary or colorPrimaryDark in java so:

```
            TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
            MainActivity.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);
            final int color = typedValue.data;
```

Comment: its not as easy as its sounds like... :)

Comment: Actually I have the toolbar so, except the fading effect. The first time that I use toolbar, I put inside of the scrollview getting the same issue than you.